# Android replacing a view with a different view but keeping the orignal constraints

Tags: java, android, view

So I have a View which i want to replace with another View. So far i've done this.

```
View child = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) child.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(child);
parent.removeView(child);
child = new MyCustomView(this.getContext());
parent.addView(child, index);
```

While this works. It also removes the constraints so the new View ends up in the top left corner. I can't seem to find a way to store the constraints placed on the original view and allow the new view to use the same.

Update:

I tried with the following

```
View child = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams childParams = child.getLayoutParams();
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) child.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(child);
parent.removeView(child);
child = new MyCustomView(this.getContext());
parent.addView(child, index,childParams);
```

It seems to be on the right track but not quite there yet.

XML:

i include my custom view in my fragments xml by the following:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        layout="@layout/my_custom_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

the my_custom_view XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="B1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timeLeftText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/peopleText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/peopleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0/5"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeLeftText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="19:30"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This view is supposed to be inflated in MyCustomView.java However the code never runs MyCustomView.Java only the XML.

The MyCustomView.java looks like this.

```
public class MyCustomView extends ConstraintLayout {

    public MyCustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, this, true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set both views in the XML and from your activity/fragment/whatever set the corresponding visibility

```
view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
view2.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However this does not work since it does not launch my custom view. It seems i have to explicitly call "new MyCustomView(this.getContext()); " for it to run.

Comment: You need to add your custom views xml code to your parent xml code in order to use what I suggest. Try to add the xml codes involved to your question to see if I can help you